# Google Fonts Suddenly Stopped Working on Wordpress Site

Tags: php, html, css, google-font-api

On my wordpress site, the Google fonts have suddenly stopped working. In the theme settings, in the typography section the google font selections are no longer showing up for the sample text either.
I've tried adding in

```
<div style="font-family: Raleway; font-size: 16px;">
```

to the individual pages and it has only worked on one of them. On all the others the website header still is not showing the correct font. I also tried putting

```
html { font-family: Raleway; }
```

to the site style.css file but it didn't make a difference. Is there anything else I can try to fix it?
The website in question is www.katerinamarie.com (**note**: Mildly non-work-safe; women in underwear.)

Comment: You need quotes around the google font name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code or theme is loading the fonts over HTTP:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='google_fonts-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Cgreek-ext%2Ccyrillic&#038;ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Since your site is hosted as HTTPS, non-HTTPS assets are blocked.

If these links are generated by your theme or a plugin, you'll need to check if they have an option to output HTTPS links to the fonts, or consult the plugin/theme authors for help.

Comment: I'm using a theme. Is there somewhere in the editor where you recommend I could try changing the links?

Comment: I would contact the theme author (or Google the name of the theme + "https fonts"). It's unlikely I'm familiar with your specific theme, and how to do this (if implemented at all) will vary from theme to theme.